# How to show a symbol from amssymb package in XeLaTeX?

Tags: beamer, xetex, amssymb

I would like to use the `\bigstar` symbol (`amssymb` package) as bullet (`itemize` environment) in Beamer using XeLaTeX but I cannot get it. Any solutions?

Answer (score 8):

You can change the symbol by:

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bigstar$}
```

Here the MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bigstar$}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
 \item foo
 \item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here the start of my log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013) (format=xelatex 2013.5.31)  8 JUN 2013 15:35
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasercs.sty
Package: beamerbasercs 2013/01/04 (rcs-revision 9a97a4eee358)
)
Document Class: beamer 2013/01/04 3.26 A class for typesetting presentations (r
cs-revision e81e0c94bcc6)
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it works in pdfLaTex but ... I have a problem with this using `XeLaTeX` compiler (I am using XeLaTeX to have an access to OTF fonts) - it does not display the star!

Comment: @VladimirS.: I used XeLaTeX. See my added header of the log file.

Comment: Thank you, Marco! Finally I have found that was my problem. To set a new bullet I used a wrong command: `\setbeamertemplate{items}[$\bigstar$]` instead of `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\bigstar$}`.

Comment: @VladimirS.: Important is that it works now.